# c program segment error from GCC compiler: concatenate two strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc

The following code raise `segment error` from **GCC** compiler:

```
char *str1 = "India";
char *str2 = "BIX";
char *str3;
str3 = strcat(str1, str2);
printf("%s %s\n", str3, str1);
```

The problem is `str3=strcat(str1, str2)`.

So my question is: for GCC Compiler, it forbids two pointers pointing to the same thing?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string). This is a very frequently asked question, please try to search around on this site before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have written, code-wise, answers your question:

```
char *str1 = "India";
char *str2 = "BIX";
//should have been
const char *str1 = "India";
const char *str2 = "BIX";
```

The variables `str1` and `str2` are being assigned the address in memory where the string CONSTANTS `India` and `BIX` are located. This memory is *read-only*. You are trying to concatenate these two strings using `strcat`. Ok, look at what it does:

```
strcat(str1, str2);
       /\   take this
       || copy  ||
       ===========
        add to end
```

This requires `str1` to point to a block of memory big enough to accomodate both itself and the chars that you're concatenating onto it. In case of string literals, this is never the case.
Also remember how I wrote your code with the `const` storage class specifier? Now look at `strcat`'s prototype:

```
char * strcat(char * destination, const char *source);
```

The function expects the first argument to be a regular `char *`, not a const. This tells you the function will attempt to change the memory the pointer points to. As others have pointed out, and I mentioned above: the memory your `str1` pointer points to is *read only*, hence the segfault.

What you could write is:

```
char str1[15] = "India";
const char *str2 = "BIX";
strcat(str1, str2);
```

That ought to work. Note that `strcat` does not check/prevent overflow. The size of the destination memory should be big enough to accomodate `strlen(source) + strlen(destination) + 1`. Using `strncat` instead would be better, still! It allows you to specify a max number of chars to be concatenated onto the destination string:

```
size_t free_space = 15;
char str1[free_space] = "India";
const char *str2 = "BIX";
free_space -= strlen(str1) + 1;//add 1 here, to ensure we'll have room for the terminating \0 char
char *str3 = strncat(
    str1,
    str2,
    free_space
);
//now we've concatenated something onto our string, keep track of free space left:
free_space -= strlen(str2);//dangerous, though -> size_t is unsigned, perhaps best do:

size_t src_len = strlen(str2);
char *str3 = strncat(
    str1,
    str2,
    free_space
);
if (src_len >= free_space)
    free_space = 0;
else
    free_space -= src_len;
```

Comment: the string between quote is called string literal and reside in ROM, a new knowledge. get that. make sense. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, string literals will be put in read-only memory region, your call to `strcat()` will try to write to this read-only memory region, therefore segment fault.

Answer (score 1):

**strcat**

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Concatenate strings
Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

**destination**
Pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

**But your destination is not pointer to an array(that is large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string) it is a pointer to sting literal,
reason for segmentation fault is you are going to write in read only memory locations**

Answer (score 1):

Trying to change a string literal invokes undefined behaviour. It's read-only even though it's not `const` qualified.

```
str3 = strcat(str1, str2);
```

The above statement calls `strcat` which has prototype

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Here `dest` is a pointer to a buffer which is large enough for the string pointed to by `src` to be appended to it. `str1` is a pointer to a string literal. Therefore, `strcat` will read the characters of the string `str2` and write them beyond the string `str1` which is illegal.
You don't need to save the return value of `strcat` in a separate `char *` variable because it modifies its first argument. So after `strcat` returns, string pointed to by `src` is appended to the one pointed to by `dest`. You should change your code to

```
#define MAX_SIZE 40

char str1[MAX_SIZE] = "India";
const char *str2 = "BIX";

// str1 must be large enough for 
// str2 to be appended to it
strcat(str1, str2);
printf("%s %s\n", str2, str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
char str1[100] = "India";    // str1 is an array for maximum 100 chars, initialized with "India"
char *str2 = "BIX";          // str2 is a pointer to the string literal "BIX" (read only)
char *str3 ;                 // str3 is pointer to char

str3 = strcat(str1, str2);   // appends "BIX" to "India" in the str1 buffer and puts str1 in str3
printf("%s %s\n", str3, str1);
```