# String manipulation in C: Is this possible?

Tags: c, string

I'm attempting to add a string at the end of another string when im doing a comparison. This how I would do it in java(might not be legit java code - been a while):

```
String input = "addl $1,%eax";

String[] registers = {"eax", "abx", "ebx", "edx"};
String s = "addl $1,%";

for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    if (input.equals(s + registers[i])) {
        printf("Match");
        // write out optimized code with specified register
    }
}
```

I'm not sure at all how to do this in C. I've tried the following but my program keeps crashing (i think because of some pointer nonsense):

```
 ...
 char *in = "Hell";
 char *pattern = "Hello";  
 const char *a[2];
 a[0] = "e";
 a[1] = "o";
 char *result = strcat(in,a[1]);
 if (strcmp(in, result) == 0) {

 printf("Helloooooooooooooooo");

 }
```

Can anyone enlighten me please how to do this kind of string manipulation in C?

Comment: `char *in = "Hell";` should be written as what it is: `const char *in = "Hell";`. It points to read-only memory, you can't write to it

Comment: `if (input == s+registers[i])`--> `if (input.equals(s+registers[i]))`

Comment: C is a Turing complete language, why isn't this possible? Except for the case there's not enough memory

Comment: why isn't what possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const char *input = "addl $1,%eax";  // For testing the code

char *registers[] = {"eax", "abx", "ebx", "edx"}; 
const char *s = "addl $1,%";
char temp[30];   // temp array to store possible commands in complete form

for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    strcpy(temp, s);  // Copy the common part to `temp`
    if (strcmp(input, strcat(temp, registers[i])) == 0) 
          // Compare the input string with possible command string
    {
        printf("Match");
        // write out optimized code with specified register
    }
}
```

You can read more about `strcpy`, `strcmp` and `strcat` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to modify string literal by using `strcat`. This will invoke undefined behavior. In C, you can't modify a string literal. The declaration

```
char *in = "Hell";
```

is equivalent to

```
char const *in = "Hell";
```

If you wanna modify it then declare `in` as an array

```
char in[6] = "Hell";
```

Suggested reading: [c-faq: Question 1.32](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: He doesn't modify a string literal, he modifies a constant string. Modifying a string literal (or at least trying to ^^) would be `strcat("hell", "o")`

Comment: @maxdev; What is the difference between a sting literal and a constant string ?

Comment: @maxdev; I haven't find the term *string constant* in the standard.

Comment: I downvoted. Your answer explains that a `const char*` can't be modified, but not how to do it right, and why. I made an edit to make clearer but you removed it.

Comment: @maxdev; I have not rejected your edit. Others have rejected it.

Comment: @maxdev no, he modifies a string literal. There are no constant strings involved here (string literals are not constant, but they are read-only).

Comment: @maxdev: Ok, let's end dis back-and-forth semantics dispute: The C standard doesn't mention constant strings but does have a section entitled: **6.4.5 String literals**. Let's conform to the standard, and agree we're talking about string literals here

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `strcat` on `in`, which is a pointer to an immutable string literal (a char array in read-only memory). By definition, you can't concatenate any other chars to that array.

I've explained this phenomenon a bit more elaborate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989228/c-program-segment-error-from-gcc-compiler-concatenate-two-strings/22989468#22989468)

Just like in the linked question, you could solve this by defining `char *in` as an *array of chars*:

```
char in[MAX_IN_LEN] = "Hell";
```

Which *copies* the chars from the string literal into the char array. Then, provided the array is big enough, you can concatenate as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following two statements are different in C.

```
char *in1 = "Hello";
char in2[6] = "Hello";
```

In the first statement  a character pointer `in1` is pointing to a string literal `Hello`. Here you can not change the string literal. 
But in the second statement you are storing the string `Hello` in a character  array `in2`.
This can be modified to something else like `in2[0] = 'h';`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to concatenate a string to a constant string. A constant string can not be modified.

When declaring a `char* test = "My string"`, the compiler automatically makes the variable `const`, because the string literal is the representation of a `const char*` in code.

[`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) wants a `char*` that contains a null-terminated string and that has enough space to concatenate the second parameter. To solve that problem correct, you have to copy the first part to a buffer and then concatenate your appendix to that buffer like this:

```
const char* source = "Hello ";
const char* appendix = "world!";

uint32_t bufLen = strlen(source) + strLen(appendix) + 1; // length of both + null-termination
char buf[bufLen];
strcpy(buf, source);
strcat(buf, appendix);
// now buf contains your concatenated string
```

Comment: Where this term *constant string* comes from ? Could give a quote from C standard ?

Comment: It's not a word from the c-standard, I just used it to describe the problem.

Comment: `test` is not const, nor are the characters it points to. A string literal is not the representation of a `const char *`, not even close. A string literal is an *array* of non-const `char` , and it is undefined behaviour to write to it.

Comment: also `size_t` makes more sense here than `uint32_t`